# Plot horizontal ray on condition in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I have the below code:

```
//@version=2
study(title="Test2", overlay=true)

HH=close>high[1]
LL=close<low[1]
lenHH = input(10, minval=1, title="HH length")
lenLL = input(10, minval=1, title="LL length")

indicator1=sma(HH, lenHH)
indicator2=sma(LL, lenLL)
indicator3=indicator1/indicator2
```

I would like to plot a horizontal ray on the close when `indicator3 = 1`

[image: example manually drawn on chart]

Tried the following but didn't work

```
//@version=2
study(title="Test2", overlay=true)

HH=close>high[1]
LL=close<low[1]
lenHH = input(10, minval=1, title="HH length")
lenLL = input(10, minval=1, title="LL length")

indicator1=sma(HH, lenHH)
indicator2=sma(LL, lenLL)
indicator3=indicator1/indicator2

plot_close = na
if (indicator3 == 1)
    plot_close := close

plot(plot_close, title="Close", color=red, linewidth=1, style=hline)
```

Found the `hline` which is used to draw horizontal lines but didn't find the horizontal ray function...

Comment: In your script HH is a boolean.... How can you calculate a sma on a boolean ? Where does your version 2 script comes from ? V2 is clearly obsolete. Post your script in v5 you will get help.

Comment: An indicator of type overlay = false, cannot plot lines on the chart